# Built In Built-in authenticators issue

Tags: authentication, heroku, higher-order-functions, built-in, heroku-cli

I am facing an issue while logging to my heroku account. After Logging I am having built-in identification although the identification is verified it is not redirection to my dashboard.
The Following attachment describes.
[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPRpC.png)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching [Heroku help center](https://help.heroku.com/) for the issue you are facing. In case if it is unique, then open a new ticket regarding this.